# MacOS X, C: shm_open fails with errno 13 Permission denied on subsequent runs

Tags: macos, semaphore, shared-memory, mmap

I'm trying to use shm_open and mmap and a semaphore to share a block of memory between two processes on MacOS X.

One problem I am having is that when I run the program a **second time**, I get a permissions error when I attempt to call **shm_open()**.

```
    #include "SharedMemory.h"

    #include <sys/mman.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <semaphore.h>
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <cassert>

    void * run_task(void * context);


    const char * mem_name = "/tmp/my_mem2";
    const char * sem_name = "/tmp/my_sem2";

    int gFileDescr = -1;

    void * gSharedMemoryAddr = NULL;
    size_t gSharedMemorySize = 0;

    sem_t * gSharedMemorySemaphore = NULL;



    typedef struct {
        completion_proc_t callback;
        void * context;
    } CallbackAndContext;

    void setupSharedMem(size_t mem_size)
    {
        assert(-1 == gFileDescr);
        assert(NULL == gSharedMemoryAddr);
        assert(NULL == gSharedMemorySemaphore);

        gSharedMemorySize = mem_size;

        gFileDescr = shm_open(mem_name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0);

        if (gFileDescr <= 0) {
            printf("Error, shm_open failed %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
            cleanup();
            exit(-1);
        }

        if (ftruncate(gFileDescr, mem_size)) {
            printf("ftruncate failed %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
            cleanup();
            exit(-1);
        }

        gSharedMemoryAddr = mmap(0, mem_size, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, gFileDescr, 0);

        if (gSharedMemoryAddr == (void *)-1) {
            gSharedMemoryAddr = NULL;
            printf("Could not map the memory: %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
            cleanup();

            exit(-1);
        }

        // open a semaphore to sync memory access.
        gSharedMemorySemaphore = sem_open(sem_name, O_CREAT, 0644, 1);
        assert(gSharedMemorySemaphore);

        int semval;
        sem_getvalue(gSharedMemorySemaphore, &semval);
        printf("The value of the semaphore is: %d\n", semval);

        sem_wait(gSharedMemorySemaphore);

    }

    void cleanup()
    {
        if (gSharedMemorySemaphore)
            sem_post(gSharedMemorySemaphore);

        if (gSharedMemorySemaphore)
            sem_close(gSharedMemorySemaphore);

        if (gSharedMemoryAddr)
            munmap(gSharedMemoryAddr, gSharedMemorySize);


        shm_unlink(mem_name);
        sem_unlink(sem_name);
    }

    void askForTask(unsigned char value, completion_proc_t completionProc, void * context)
    {
        unsigned char * memptr = (unsigned char *) gSharedMemoryAddr;

        memptr[0] = value;

        CallbackAndContext * candc = (CallbackAndContext *)malloc(sizeof(CallbackAndContext));
        candc->callback = completionProc;
        candc->context = context;

        pthread_t myThread;
        pthread_create(&myThread, NULL, run_task, (void *)candc);
    }

    void * run_task(void * context)
    {
        CallbackAndContext * candc = (CallbackAndContext *)context;

        completion_proc_t comp_proc = NULL;
        void * callback_context = NULL;

        if (candc) {
            comp_proc = candc->callback;
            callback_context = candc->context;

            free(candc);
        }




        printf("My Task runner started.\n");

        // this will cause the task to start.
        if (sem_post(gSharedMemorySemaphore)) {
            printf("Error posting to semaphore: %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
            cleanup();
            exit(-1);
        }

        // wait for task to be done.
        if (sem_wait(gSharedMemorySemaphore)) {
            printf("Error acquiring semaphore: %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
            cleanup();
            exit(-1);
        }



        printf("Task over\n");
        if (comp_proc) {
            comp_proc(callback_context);
        }

        return NULL;
    }
```

In my main.mm file, it looks like this:

```
    #define SHARED_MEMORY_BLOCK_SIZE 5000

    unsigned char gValue = 0;

    extern void * gSharedMemoryAddr;

    NSConditionLock * taskLock;
    enum {
         waiting
        ,done
    };

    void MyCompletionProc(void * context)
    {
        assert(gSharedMemoryAddr);
        unsigned char * valPtr = (unsigned char *)gSharedMemoryAddr;

        printf("Task Complete Callback: %s\n", gValue == valPtr[1] ? "success" : "fail" );



        [taskLock lock];
        [taskLock unlockWithCondition:done];
    }

    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {
        taskLock = [[NSConditionLock alloc] initWithCondition: waiting];

        setupSharedMem(SHARED_MEMORY_BLOCK_SIZE);

        NSDate * start_time = [NSDate date];

        for (;[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:start_time] < 30.0f;) {

            askForTask(++gValue, MyCompletionProc, NULL);
            [taskLock lockWhenCondition:done];
            [taskLock unlockWithCondition:waiting];
            sleep(1);

        }

        cleanup();

        return 0;
    }
```

(Hopefully mixing Objective-C in there won't confuse people.)

The first time I run the program it appears to work properly calling the askTask about once a second. After 30 seconds, it calls "cleanup" and exits.

On subsequent runs (unless I change the name of mem_name/sem_name), I get a permissions error. It goes away when I reboot the computer until the next time.

What am I doing wrong and how can I "reset" this or prevent it from getting into this state?

Follow up: it appears shm_unlink fails in cleanup() with permission denied. I don't know why.

Answer (score 4):

Solved.

The problem is that when shm_open is called, you need to specify a "mode" that gives the user permissions to access the shared memory - otherwise you get the permissions error when you unlink.

```
gFileDescr = shm_open(mem_name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0);


gFileDescr = shm_open(mem_name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

I found the answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/native-client-reviews/EHHHfK_xPZ4